# How to chain sql queries which are dependent on each other in node

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, async.js

I am looking to fetch data from on query and then run a array loop over a item stored in result. then Fetch data from another query using keys from the array fetched from first query.

What ever I have tried is not giving me the desired result as array loops runs out before the sql queried finishes and produce the desired result.

I have tried solution with async.series function and async.map function but result is not coming in the desired sequence.

This is the output From first query.
My objective is to add array of option details in place option id which is returned from first query.

```
[
  {
    "id": 318,
    "name": "Sandwich Dosa",
    "price": 140,
    "option": ''
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "name": "Spi. Prem Uttappa",
    "price": 131,
    "option": '1,2'
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "name": "Paneer Spl. Prem Uttappa",
    "price": 140,
    "option": ''
  },
  {
    "id": 321,
    "name": "Spl. Spicy Uttappa",
    "price": 131,
    "option": ''
  }
]
```

Looking to build as

```
[
  {
    "id": 318,
    "name": "Sandwich Dosa",
    "price": 140,
    "option": ''
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "name": "Spi. Prem Uttappa",
    "price": 131,
    "option": [{
      id:'1',
      name:'Regular',
      price:'89',
    },
    {
      id:'2',
      name:'Spicy',
      price:'119',
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "name": "Paneer Spl. Prem Uttappa",
    "price": 140,
    "option": ''
  },
  {
    "id": 321,
    "name": "Spl. Spicy Uttappa",
    "price": 131,
    "option": ''
  }
]
```

This is my current code through which I am trying to achive

```
var data = {
  "error": 1,
  "items": ""
};

connection.query("SELECT * FROM  items WHERE status=1 AND  menu_grp_id=" + req.params.sid, function(err, rows, fields) {
  var items = []; // temporary holder for items

  if(err) { throw err } else {
  if(rows.length != 0) {
    for (var key in rows) {
      // Holding Item properties
      var item = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        price: '',
        option: ''
      };
      item.id = rows[key].id;
      item.name = rows[key].item_name;
      item.price = rows[key].price;
      item.option = rows[key].option;

      items.push(item); // pushing item object into    items array
    }
    data["error"] = 0;      
    data['items'] = items;
    if((data['items'].length > 0)) {
      for(i = 0; i < data['items'].length; i++) {
        if(data['items'][i].option == "") {
          data['items'][i].option = [];
        } else {
          var array = data['items'][i].option.split(",")
          data['items'][i].option = array;
        }
      }
    }
    res.json(data); // sending JSON Data
  } else {
    data["error"] = 0;
    data["items"] = 'No item Found..';
    res.json(data); //  sending JSON Data
  }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm a bit late here, but  I think that async.waterfall is what you need.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM  items WHERE status=1 AND  menu_grp_id=" + req.params.sid, function(err, rows, fields) {
            //manipulate your data as you wish
            data = synchronousManipolutionOfYourData();
            cb(null, data);
        });
    },
    function(data, cb){
        //data here stores the data you passed as a second parameter in the preciding callback
       //execute your second query with the data you got from the first query.
       cb(null, dataManipulatedAfterSecondQuery)//and so on
    }, 
    //other functions if you need other queries
], function(){
    done;
});
```